# Is it possible to corrupt Solana Smart Contract from client side?

Tags: anchor, smartcontracts, solana

I am following [this tutorial](https://dev.to/dabit3/the-complete-guide-to-full-stack-solana-development-with-react-anchor-rust-and-phantom-3291) creating smart contract on local network. Everything works fine however when I modified the client smart contract ended up in "corrupted" state.  I am having trouble understanding what has happened. Here is the contract :

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
 
declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");
 
#[program]
mod mysolanaapp {
    use super::*;
 
    pub fn create(ctx: Context<Create>) -> ProgramResult {
        let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;
        base_account.count = 0;
        Ok(())
    }
 
    pub fn increment(ctx: Context<Increment>) -> ProgramResult {
        let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;
        base_account.count += 1;
        Ok(())
    }
}
 
// Transaction instructions
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Create<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 16 + 16)]
    pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program <'info, System>,
}
 
// Transaction instructions
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Increment<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,
}
 
// An account that goes inside a transaction instruction
#[account]
pub struct BaseAccount {
    pub count: u64,
}
```

and working client code is :

```
const anchor = require('@project-serum/anchor');
const { SystemProgram } = anchor.web3;
 
 
(async () => {
 
    const provider = anchor.Provider.local();
    anchor.setProvider(provider);
 
    // The Account to create.
    const myAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
 
    // Read the generated IDL.
    const idl = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('./hello.json', 'utf8'));
 
    // Address of the deployed program.
    const programId = new anchor.web3.PublicKey('GrfgF4vWfVEDsLKHxiB5Q6yfYhziubLY9M8VVxyTEc6o');
 
    // Generate the program client from IDL.
    const program = new anchor.Program(idl, programId);
 
    // Execute the RPC.
    await program.rpc.create({
        accounts: {
            baseAccount: myAccount.publicKey,
            user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        },
        signers: [myAccount],
    });
 
    /* Fetch the account and check the value of count */
    let account = await program.account.baseAccount.fetch(myAccount.publicKey);
    console.log('Count 0: ', account.count.toString())
 
    await program.rpc.increment({
        accounts: {
            baseAccount: myAccount.publicKey,
        },
    });
 
    account = await program.account.baseAccount.fetch(myAccount.publicKey);
    console.log('Count 1: ', account.count.toString())
 
})();
```

However this code generate new account each time it is called. Since I wanted to keep data persistent I tried to replace account generation with loading my local key-pair that I used to deploy the contract :

```
const secKey = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('/home/username/.config/solana/id.json', 'utf8'));
const arr = Uint8Array.from(secKey)

const myAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(arr);
```

However this results in an error:

> SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: This account may not be used to pay transaction fees

What is even more odd to me is that reverting the changes do not help and client is failing all the time. To my surprise even deploying the contract again is no longer possible as anchor returns following error :

> Upgrade authority: /home/username/.config/solana/id.json Deploying
> program "mysolanaapp"... Program path:
> /home/username/workspace/solana/mysolanaapp/target/deploy/mysolanaapp.so...
> ==================================================================== Recover the intermediate account's ephemeral keypair file with
> `solana-keygen recover` and the following 12-word seed phrase:
> ==================================================================== exact embody actor side tongue dutch pave crop pair ill ability case
> ==================================================================== To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the
> [PROGRAM_ADDRESS_SIGNER] argument to `solana deploy` or as the
> [BUFFER_SIGNER] to `solana program deploy` or `solana write-buffer'. Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the [BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to` solana program close`.
> ==================================================================== Error: Account allocation failed: RPC response error -32002:
> Transaction simulation failed: This account may not be used to pay
> transaction fees  There was a problem deploying: Output { status:
> ExitStatus(ExitStatus(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

I would very much appreciate a hint. What happened? Did I manage to corrupt the contract from the client?

Answer (score 3):

This is all expected behavior.  The error:

> SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: This account may not be used to pay transaction fees

gives all the most important information.  In Solana, when you send a transaction to the network, some account owned by the system program (https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/programs#system-program) must sign the transaction, in order to deduct the fee.  When you run the `create` instruction on `myAccount` with your program, that account is getting assigned to your program, and so it is no longer owned by the system program, making it impossible to sign transactions.  More information about the account model, and specifically about ownership, at https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#ownership-and-assignment-to-programs

All this to say, to solve your problem, you need to sign transactions with a different account.  You can use `solana-keygen new -o new_account.json` then `solana airdrop .1 new_account.json` so it has funds, then use it as the signer as needed.